# AWS CodePipeline CDK TypeScript

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

The `install commands` in the Build Step of the AWS CodePipeline do not update when there are changes made in the AWS CDK Code (TypeScript) and are pushed to the repository. The **Buildspec** section under the ***Build details*** of the project has the same configuration as when it was created.

Is there a way to fix it? We've made some changes to the BuildStep CDK but does not take effect on the AWS CodeBuild configuration details. I'm only new to AWS CodeBuild and CodePipeline. Any answer/suggestion would be a great help.

**Sample Code**

```js
const pipeline = new CodePipeline(this, 'SamplePipeline', {
    pipelineName: 'SamplePipeline',
    synth: new CodeBuildStep('BuildSynthStep', {
            input: source,
            buildEnvironment: {
                buildImage: codebuild.LinuxBuildImage.STANDARD_5_0
            },
            installCommands: [
                'install_command_1',
                'install_command_2',
                ...
                'install_command_n'
            ],
            commands: [
                'command_2',
                ...
                'command_n'
            ],
        }
    )
});
```

**Artifact Provider**: Amazon S3

Comment: What pipeline construct are you using?  It would be helpful to have some minimal code in the question.

Comment: I would suggest you to use a seperate yml file for your build commands  and include that file during the codebuild project creation.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the `pipelines` module - it will only be changed after the `SelfUpdate` step, which mutates the pipeline.

Comment: @fedonev I added the sample code that we are using for the Pipeline.

Comment: @JatinMehrotra thanks for the suggestion, it is well appreciated. But one of the requirements of the project is to use an AWS CDK code for it.

Comment: My suggestion was to do this using CDK only. I have posted a solution and I have tested this with my cdk implementation and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The self-mutation of a CDK Pipeline is only applied, when you change something on an application stage (precisely CDK Stage) or other phases after the synth codebuild job.

If you have something running before, e.g. unit tests, then you won't get into the self-update job.

So, what are your options now?

Well, changes according to a pipeline itself are mostly done manually.
So you have to re-run a `cdk deploy PipelineStack` on your local machine with your changes committed to the source branch aside.

Comment: By saying to run a `cdk deploy PipelineStack`, does that mean to redeploy the PipelineStack for it to read the changes to the AWS CodeBuild configuration?

Comment: exactly.
i edited my answer to make it more clear hopefully.

Comment: @undefine97  See the docs for a description of the CDK pipeline's [self-mutating](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#at-a-glance) behaviour and related advice about [working on the pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.pipelines-readme.html#working-on-the-pipeline).